# How to bundle puppeteer to use in a web application?

Tags: javascript, module, puppeteer, async.js

I am exporting test function this way: `export default test;`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function test() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');

    // Get the "viewport" of the page, as reported by the page.
    const dimensions = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return {
            width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio
        };
    });

    console.log('Dimensions:', dimensions);

    await browser.close();
};
```

I am importing above `example.js` file by `import test from './example'`. In that I am getting error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'ws'
    at webpackMissingModule (WebSocketTransport.js:16)
    at Object../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js`

I installed `ws`, but still the same error. 
Looks like it is because I am trying to bundle puppeteer to use in a web application. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is there an error of some kind when using the same `export default test;`?

Comment: When I import it `import test from './example'`, I am getting this error: `./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ws' in '../node_modules/puppeteer/lib'`

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with how you export the function. What is your environment? Node.js?

Comment: I am using webpack. I have installed `ws`. I have `"ws": "^6.1.2"` under `dependencies`

Comment: It's not possible to use puppeteer in a web app in a browser as it is using a Cromium itself, but have a look at `puppeteer-core`, maybe that'll do.

Comment: @user7331530 have you found a solution to this?